# Frezze (or fix) a Header from Show/Hide menu in FlexiGrid

Tags: javascript, flexigrid

I am having problem and searching here and there for a solution to Fix or Freeze a Table header from Show/Hide menu and will be shown/hidden as it is initiated. For this I have added a property in the **colModel**.

I give the name of the property is **"fixCol"**. If any header is to be fixed and will never be hidden or show (will not be in list of Show/Hide menu), just give the value **"true"** of **"fixCol"**.

Example :: colModel : [{display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center', fixCol:true},
{display: 'ISO', name : 'iso', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'}],

This **fixCol** will be checked in the **flexigrid.js** file. There have a function

```
**`if (p.colModel) //create model if any
{ }`**
```

Go to there and add the following code inside the checking of `if( cm ) {}`

```
 `if (cm.fixCol) {
                   $(th).attr('title', 'fixCol'+i);
    }`
```

Now update another code where the **checkbox** (add column control) is added for Show/Hide menu. Give a condition there as

```
if( kcol.title){}
else { $('tbody', g.nDiv).append('<tr><td class="ndcol1"><input type="checkbox" ' + chk + ' class="togCol" value="' + cn + '" /></td><td class="ndcol2">' + this.innerHTML + '</td></tr>'); }
```

This will check if the Header has any title or not. If any title exists that means we have set that as fix header.

This will help you to remove the Header from Show/Hide menu in FlexiGrid.

Please comment and suggest me to for any issue or bug.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution... is there a sample showing this column header fixed on horizontal scrolling?

Comment: No, There have option to Hide any header column from Show/Hide control panel of the table header (see the right side of a header column and click on the down arrow to see the control panel. There you will get checkbox showing the header list which can be toggled by checking/un checking the box.)

I have updated the JS by which you can remove any header column option from that list and you can fix that column which can not be hidden/ visible (if initially it is hidden)

Check it:   https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/issues/99